# JQuery, getting 'undefined' message when trying to access the ID of a textarea

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to update the ID of a form element using jquery's attr() function. For debugging purposes.

I seem to be able to assign values to other elements, such as attr('title','test') works just fine. It's only when I want to update the ID.

My entire reason for wanting to update the ID, is that I am building form fields dynamically and need to assign them ID's.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <script>
   function addQuestion(){
   $('#question0Container').clone().appendTo('#questionArea');
   $('#add').attr('id','newid');
   alertText = $('#add').attr('id'); 
   alert("The id is:" + alertText);
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="questionArea">
  <div id="question0Container">
  <textarea id="question0" name="question0"></textarea><p>Answers</p>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" onClick="addQuestion();" id="add" title="Add a question">add question</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the id, but your selector still uses the old ID. So, no element is found.
Change this:

```
alertText = $('#add').attr('id');
```

to this:

```
alertText = $('#newid').attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks, just realized that :p

Answer (score 1):

I think you're setting the ID of the button, not the cloned question.

Once the question is cloned and written to the DOM you'll have two questions with the same ID, so set the ID while you still have a reference to it, like so:

```
$('#question0Container').clone().attr('id','newid').appendTo('#questionArea');
```

And remove the next line

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a new ID to the `<a>` with `$('#add').attr('id','newid');`, therefor the selector `$('#add').attr('id');` will return nothing.

I'm guessing you wanted to assign an id to the textarea that was just cloned, in that case you should use something like:

```
   function addQuestion(){
      $newTextarea = $('#question0Container').clone().appendTo('#questionArea');
      $newTextarea.attr('id','newid');
      alert("The id of the new textarea is:" + $newTextarea.attr("id"));
   }
```

Comment: Yea, this is exactly what I want to do. Thanks bjorn!